# Changing The chars on a file (C programming)

Tags: c

Well.....I'm new at C programming and i'm stuck in a exercise. I need to create and write on a .txt file and change the letters(or chars if you prefer) to the next 3 in the alphabet. So if i have The "Dog" it needs to be changed to "Fri" for example, and of course i need to output it.

That's what i have right now, the code is incomplete because i cant figure out how to change any other letter and because even this is not working as it should.

it creates a file, it writes a bit in it, closes it just to be sure it was saved properly, opes it again to read the file than proceeds to change the letters in it.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file1.txt","w");

    fprintf(fp,"Hello World");
    fprintf(fp,"HELLO WORLD");

    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");

    while(c!=EOF){
        c=getc(fp);
        if(c=="x"){
            c="a";
        }else if(c=="y"){
            c="b";
        }else if(c=="z"){
            c="c";
        }else if(c=="X"){
            c="A";
        }else if(c=="Y"){
            c="B";
        }else(c=="Z"){
            c="C";
        }
        putchar(c);

    }

    fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    fclose(fp);

    return 0; 
}
```

Update/ Edit:

Ok so I've managed i wasn't exactly understanding what i was supposed to change in the code or where to place all your answers in the code so i tried a leap of faith here and for what i understood from your suggestions the char c can be handled as a 8-bit integer, so i simply tried c+=3 after it checks all the other if statements. The code now works.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file1.txt","w");

    fprintf(fp,"Hello World");
    fprintf(fp,"HELLO WORLD");

    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");

    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF){
        if (!isalnum(c))
            continue;

        if(c=='x'){
            c='a';
        }else if(c=='y'){
            c='b';
        }else if(c=='z'){
            c='c';
        }else if(c=='X'){
            c='A';
        }else if(c=='Y'){
            c='B';
        }else if(c=='Z'){
            c='C';
        }else{
            c+=3;
        }
        putchar(c);

    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0; 
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions folks. They helped a lot, and i know those if statements could have been a bit better but then again i'm new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Why all the `if`s? You could just do something like `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') c = (((c - 'a') + 3) % 26) + 'a';` (and similarly for the capital letters).

Comment: `c` is a char  variable, while `"Z"` is char* (kind of string) literal. You should use `'z'`, etc.

Comment: The type of `"x"` is `char*`, not `char`. Change it to `'x'` to begin with. Do the same for all other letters.

Comment: Just a little tip here, no need to do if/switch statements, try this for example: `char c = 'a'; printf("c: %c\n", c + 3);`

Comment: F is not three letters in the alphabet away from D, and the same for I and J. Did you mean "Grj"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way you could achieve this is if you simply add 3 to the character values. The tricky part is when you your offset falls off the alphabet (ex. you'd offset the ascii `z` by 3, you'd get `}`).

You could try something like this:

```
if ( (c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z') )
{
  c += 3;
  if (c > 'z') // If the character falls off the alphabet, Start over at 'a'
    c = c - 'z' + 'a';
}
if ( (c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z') )
{
  c += 3;
  if (c > 'Z') // If the character falls off the alphabet, Start over at 'a'
    c = c - 'Z' + 'A';
}
```

here `c` is the character that you are modifying.

Comment: Ok let me test this one, i didn't know i could use the char c like a number.(with the < and > i mean).

Comment: A char is in fact a signed, 8-bit integer. So you can use chars in any operation where you can use a number.

Comment: Hum..it didn't work, i think it may bee better to check if the char c ain't one of the ending alphabet letters (x,y or z) first, if not then i use the normal method.

Comment: @TamásSzabó It's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned, and it's size is `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: @unwind: Thanks for clarifying. So far on every platform I used it was 8 bits & signed. But honestly, I never checked the specs.

Comment: Nitpick: Doesn't plain C require `/* .. */` comments? My compiler settings warn me of this.

Comment: Where exactly do i add this in the code, becasue i'm trying everything and it simply is not working.
PS: When i say i'm fairly new to C, i mean i'm fairly new to programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map a to d, b to e, .... x to a, y to b and z to c, you could try this:

```
if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
 c += 3;
}

if (c > 'z') {
 c = 'a' + (c - 'z' - 1);
}
```

Also, putchar writes to the standard output. You should use putc:

```
putc(c,fp);
```

Also, as others have pointed out a character literal is enclosed in single quotes.

EDIT:
You should have this code in the while loop that reads character by character from the file, as follows:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fpRead)) != EOF) { //file pointer to read
 if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
  c += 3;
 }

 if (c > 'z') {
  c = 'a' + (c - 'z' - 1);
 }
 putc(c,fpWrite); //different file to write to
}
```

As @unwind as pointed out, you have to be careful when you read from and write to the same file. I don't think that is your intention. In case, you want to over write the same file. Read into an array. Then open the file in 'w' mode to write the array into that file. The previous contents will be over-written.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can't compare `EOF` against a value of type `char`, it won't fit. You need `int`.

Something like this:

```
int c;

while((c = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF)
{
  if(islower(c))
  {
    const int loc = c - 'a'; /* Non-portable! */
    loc = (loc + 3) % 26;
    c = 'a' + loc;
  }
  else if(isupper(c))
  {
    const int loc = c - 'A'; /* Non-portable! */
    loc = (loc + 3) % 26;
    c = 'A' + loc;
  }
  putc(c, fp_out);
}
```

Note: the above is *non-portable* since it assumes that the characters A-Z and a-z are encoded in adjacent locations. This is **not** guaranteed by C, so the code will break on systems using such character sets. For typical modern systems using some derivative of ASCII (or UTF-8), it will work.

There's also obviously a lot of duplication in the lower/upper branches, that could be refactored.

Note that the above uses two `FILE *` pointers, since you can't read and write to the same file and overwrite in place.